# Run two suspend functions in parallel and return when first one returns

Tags: android, kotlin, async-await, kotlin-coroutines, suspend

I want to run to suspend functions in parallel and return result once the faster one of them returns result.
I tried doing the following, but I think it only returns when both of them have finished and it takes too much time, since I'm waiting for both.

```
val coroutineScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main)
val a = coroutineScope.async {
    a(context)
}
val b = coroutineScope.async {
    b(context)
}

val results = listOf(a, b).awaitAll()

return if (results.any { it is RunSuccess }) {
    ...
} else {
    ...
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`select`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/select-expression.html#selecting-from-channels) as follows :

```
suspend fun doWork(): String = coroutineScope {
   select<String> {
      async { work1() }.onAwait { it }
      async { work2() }.onAwait { it }
   }.also {
      coroutineContext.cancelChildren()
   }
}
```

On this example is returning a `String` but you can change it with whatever you want, it depends on what your `work` is returning.

In case you are looking for more `functional programming` version you can use `raceN` from [`Arrow`](https://github.com/arrow-kt/arrow/blob/main/arrow-libs/fx/arrow-fx-coroutines/src/commonMain/kotlin/arrow/fx/coroutines/Race2.kt)

Where you have this method

```
public suspend inline fun <A, B> raceN(crossinline fa: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> A, crossinline fb: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> B): Either<A, B> =
  raceN(Dispatchers.Default, fa, fb)
```

And then you call this `raceN` method

```
public suspend inline fun <A, B> raceN(
  ctx: CoroutineContext = EmptyCoroutineContext,
  crossinline fa: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> A,
  crossinline fb: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> B
): Either<A, B> =
  coroutineScope {
    val a = async(ctx) { fa() }
    val b = async(ctx) { fb() }
    select<Either<A, B>> {
      a.onAwait.invoke { Either.Left(it) }
      b.onAwait.invoke { Either.Right(it) }
    }.also {
      when (it) {
        is Either.Left -> b.cancelAndJoin()
        is Either.Right -> a.cancelAndJoin()
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you. Does the `select` answer mean that both the processes will run until the end though? I mean, I should just use the first one that finishes as soon as it finishes and the second one should continue running in the background - not stop the running of the second one, right?

Comment: No this first solution with `select` stops the running of the second one

Answer (score 1):

Arrow fx has a nice method called raceN.

https://arrow-kt.io/docs/apidocs/arrow-fx-coroutines/arrow.fx.coroutines/race-n.html